# Sending an object with a post request (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, http-post

So I'm creating an object named "ob" in my post request function, and it prints the right thing to the console when I use console.log, but when I try to send that object the returned value does not resolve to an object. Is using "res.status(200).send(ob)" wrong here?

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

        var ob = {
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            username: req.body.username
        }

        console.log("object is");
        console.log(ob);

        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(ob));  
}
```

I tried returning both JSON.stringify(ob) as well as ob but they both don't return an object

Comment: Why not using `res.json`? Toy have to call `.end()` after `.send()`. `res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(ob)).end()`

Comment: I tried json before too but it also didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use `res.status(200).json(ob)` instead.That would send the `ob` as an object rather than `JSON.stringify(ob)` which converts a JSON into a string.